# PHP Trait conflict when class implements interface

Tags: php, oop, interface, traits

I have a class that implements an Interface for `execute` method.

The interface forces the `execute` method to have two arguments with some type hints.

Also I'm using a trait which has an `execute` method, but with different functionality and signature. I alter the trait method name by using :

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {

   use MyTrait 
   {
      execute as protected commanderExecute;
   }

   public function execute(SomeInterface $arg1, SomeInterface2 $arg2)
   {
       // do something
   }

}
```

When I try to run the app it throws a Fatal error exception with following message:

> Trait method commanderExecute has not been applied, because there are collisions with other trait methods on ...

Comment: [Can not reproduce](http://codepad.viper-7.com/tYe3HN) (another, more useful sample is [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uoa98W) )

Comment: Please add the MyTrait and MyInterface code.

Comment: Can't reproduce; pasting `trait MyTrait {public function execute(){}} interface MyInterface{} class MyClass implements MyInterface {use MyTrait{execute as protected commanderExecute;}public function execute(){}}` into the PHP shell causes no error.

Comment: Voting to close due to inability to reproduce. You need to provide us with sufficient code to actually cause the error message.

Comment: @AlmaDo Your links both go to "hello world" programs for me.

Comment: Worked: http://3v4l.org/K86Bt   Class can overwrite method in trait. It you still got error, need more error message, to tell which execute()/commanderExecute() is collision with.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {

    use MyTrait 
    {
        MyTrait::execute as protected commanderExecute;
    }

    public function execute(SomeInterface $arg1, SomeInterface2 $arg2)
    {
        // do something
    }

}
```